# Integrating Fabric with Android using AS - Crashlytics Error

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am trying to use twitter-kit for android. I followed all the steps mentioned here - https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating

The build fails with following message -
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.

> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

"Invalid API key for crashlyics" - But I dont want to use crashlytics. (atleast for now). How to overcome the above issue? I need to integrate only twitter-kit to display tweets for particular #tag.